# Track archives with git

Tags: git

I have an archive (`*.xpi`) file in a git repository. How can I track the archive to get a more meaningful `git diff` then simply `Binary files ... differ`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not track `.xpi` file. Track the source files which are content of that `.xpi`.

If the plugin in question is yours - then just add directory with source files into git controlled tree.

If the plugin is someone else's and you just download the ready to use `.xpi` from firefox's site - do you really need track the minute changes between versions? History, readme, etc should be enough.

But if you really want, you can just unpack the archive (simple `unzip` will help) and do a `diff` on the unpacked files.

Or you can ask author of the plugin (or just read the readme file), find there this plugin is stored (github most likely) and just checkout/pull the freshest version with a full-scale diff. As additional benefit - you would get an ability to improve the plugin.